# Add attribute to Table class from pandastable

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to add a new attribute to the class `table` from the package `pandastable` by inheritance. I use the following code for this:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandastable import Table
import tkinter as tk

class MyTable(Table):

    def __init__(self, list_items, *args, **kwargs):
        self.list_items = list_items
        super(MyTable, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

top = tk.Tk()
top.geometry("300x300")

df = pd.DataFrame()
df["column1"] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
df["column2"] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
df["column3"] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
df["column4"] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]

frame = tk.Frame(top)
frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

pt = MyTable(frame, dataframe=df)
pt.focus_set()
pt.show()

top.mainloop()
```

When I run the code, I get following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "....py", line 47, in <module>
    pt = MyTable(frame, dataframe=df)
  File "/....py", line 9, in __init__
    super(MyTable, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "...e.py", line 134, in __init__
    self.doBindings()
  File "....py", line 262, in doBindings
    self.parentframe.master.bind_all("<KP_8>", self.handle_arrow_keys)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'master'
```

The error occurs in the package function `doBindings`. but why does it occur only after I have changed the `__init__` function?

Comment: you need to provide `list_items` as the first argument to the `pt = MyTable(list_items, frame, dataframe=df)`, also just use `super()` instead of `super(MyTable, self)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to pass the `parent` option to `Table()`.  Second suggest to use keyword argument `list_items` instead of positional argument.

```py
class MyTable(Table):
    # add parent argument and remove *args
    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        # get the keyword argument 'list_items' if provided, otherwise set it to None
        self.list_items = kwargs.pop('list_items', None)
        # pass required parent argument to Table class
        super().__init__(parent, **kwargs)
```